# RStudio interface / behavior changes in 1.0.136

Tags: rstudio

Various things are different in 1.0.136, e.g. running code with ctrl-enter has all sorts of strange behavior in an RMarkdown document, running code that has a syntax error somehow leads to all of the code being run in a block above (below?) the wrong code, etc. Sorry for not posting an MWE, but at the moment I just want to know if anyone is aware of these new "features" and if so how they can be turned off or better yet how I can just downgrade to the previous version of RStudio (which I can't currently find on the website).

Comment: Seriously, I just need to get some work done at the moment; I guess I should use Vim, at least those fine folks never change anything on me. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should ask on the RStudio support forums.

Comment: Fair enough...!

Answer (score 1):

Yes they changed some default settings that were present in the old interface.

Change the setting in markdown next to the knit button, from:

Chunk Output Inline -> Chunk Output in Console

[Pictured here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73enz.png)

You can probably mess with the  the Global Setting->Rmarkdowns under Tools to get it back the way it was before, but this was the fastest way for me.